# Best design pattern for work queue project

Tags: angular, design-patterns, java-8

I need to design a project for work queue system, Below are the actors and there roles.

1. Maker
2. Checker
3. Client

Maker creates a task and submits it the task moves to checker's queue from where checker will pick it up and review it, if encounters any issue the task is again send back to makers queue with comments. If all is fine the checker submits the task and it moves to client's queue. From there the respective client will pick up the task and if he finds the task is improper he can again send the task back to makers or checkers queue for rework with comments. If all is fine he can submit the task if with proper information and the task is closed. Also the task can be reopened in future.

The technology stack for the above is as below
Java ver.8, spring boot 1.5.9, Angular JS 4.0, maven 3.3.9

As I have not designed any project till now, need help with which design pattern I should proceed.

Comment: As you have mentioned , you first need the complete archutecture of your problem . In your problem you will need 2 queues one for maker and then one for checker. Then break down it into smaller problem and try to visualise where you can use the design pattern. Design pattern are for handling the creational, behaviour of objects.  Since you task first needs to be validated then and then send further , you can use template design patter here.